# Making a class not inherited

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I am trying to create a c# class, but I dont want it to be inherited. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`sealed` is the word you're looking for, and a link for [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx)

```
public sealed class MyClass
{

}
```

And then just create your class as normal, however you won't be able to inherit from it.

You can however still inherit from a different class like so

```
public sealed class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the `PostMan's` answer, we can achieve the same by making the Class *Constructor* `Private`.

```
class NotInheritable
    {

        private NotInheritable()
        {
            //making the constructor private
        }
    }

 class Derived : NotInheritable { }
```

Now the class `NotInheritable` will not be inheritable, as the compiler will prompt the error:

> `NotInheritable.NotInheritable()` is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: `code formatting` is mainly used for code. You can also format with bold and italic text.